# wercker internal/docker-push fails

Tags: push, dockerhub, wercker

Using the following (excerpt from) the wercker file:

```
- internal/docker-push:
    tag: pp2-ui
    username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
    password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
    repository: rudivd/test
    ports: 8081
    cmd: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    registry:  https://hub.docker.com
```

I cannot get the image to be pushed on the (existing !) repo on my dockerhub account. No error is displayed on wercker in this step , just :

```
Pushing to registry
Preparing: 108f467b1185
Preparing: fbea414e2b72
Preparing: df37ebe42479
Preparing: 63e3aeadf993
Preparing: 4fe15f8d0ae6
```

But my image does not show up in hub.docker.com under this account / repo.

Any ideas here !? (NOTE, I checked UID/Passwd environmet vars they are OK).

Rudi

Answer (score 3):

fixed.

uid seemed wrong, you need the username, not the E-mail address although this works for logging into the docker hub itself.

R.